# Is it possible to pass Azure SAS token in headers/cookies/post body?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We would very much like to avoid the update of the url to the file in our application when the SAS token is updated.
Is there a way to pass the token not in the url?
I did not find any info on that and I think it is impossible but thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, it has to be part of the url.

What you can do is write a little proxy app service that operated in the way you want by passing it as a header and translating it for you. Alternatively (I am not 100% sure) but you may be able to map it in API Gateway. [Have a rummage around here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetQueryStringParameter).

Comment: unfortunately that's not an option since all of the traffic would go through that proxy Too expensive

Comment: Yes, it would be quite expensive. You'll need a way to manage the SAS in the URL or use Azure AD auth if possible.

Comment: A proxy app can be a CloudFlare Worker - this way you don't pay for the traffic, only for the requests.

Comment: A proxy can also respond with 30x redirect to azure storage with SAS so that only header traffic needs to be paid.